# Converting SOAP to REST Responses and vice versa in APIGEE

Tags: apigee

North Bound Client can send only SOAP Request , while SOUTH Bound can Only accept REST Request and send Response as only REST

Is there any policy in apigee to convert REST to SOAP and vice versa

Please explain how to convert otherwise

Comment: You don't *convert* REST to SOAP. They can coexist, REST is an architectural style, a design concept, while SOAP is a protocol, a contract for communication.

Comment: North bound payload is SOAP Service i need to convert the same into REST Payload and send to SOUTH Bound how can i achieve this

Comment: I need to Transforming payload messages from REST to SOAP and SOAP to REST

Answer (score 0):

When creating a new API proxy, you can use an existing WSDL to create a REST to SOAP mapping to your backend service.  Hopefully that does what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Use **Assign Message Policy**.

For example:
North Bound Client SOAP Request -> **Assign Message Policy To Create REST Request Payload** -> South Bound Client REST Request

For more details on Assign Message policy, can refer to https://docs.apigee.com/api-platform/reference/policies/assign-message-policy.